# How do I search my Firebase database for a certain key in my Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently making an Android app that allows Facebook sign-in and for each user, stores their email address (from Facebook) along with a couple integer variables in my database.

Upon login, I want my app to check if my database contains the email address of the logged on user. If it does, I proceed with the app functionality, if not, I create a new entry in my database for that user, with an email address and the associated integers.

How can I formulate a query or request that searches my database for a given email string? I am not very experienced with Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Using [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login) for your Facebook sign-in would give every user a unique id generated by Firebase. 
This id is returned to you in the code when login is successful. You could then retrieve the user's email from the returned object.

Assuming you're using Firebase's real time database to store your info, you could check out their official docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data) on how to use your DatabaseReference DataSnapshot to query the database